# Does the human brain emit ULF waves?

Tags: electromagnetic-radiation, biophysics

In the book *The Electric Universe* by David Bodanis, the author writes that "invisible waves stream out of from our brains with a wavelength of about 200 miles".

Is it true that the brain produces ULF waves?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Technically, yes. A wavelength of 200 miles corresponds to a frequency of about 90 Hertz, which is within the frequency of human brain waves (1 to 100 Hertz). Since brain waves correspond to moving charge, you presumably do emit some 90 Hertz radiation. It should be emphasized that this is an extremely small amount which is completely undetectable.

If the book you're reading uses that to justify some mystical nonsense, just toss it in the trash. The fact that human brains emit a negligible but nonzero amount of radiation is not very interesting, because *everything* does, constantly. If you're immersed in water, every motion you make will produce some tiny water waves. Similarly, every motion you make produces some disturbance in the electromagnetic field. And all of these disturbances are dwarfed by what comes out of your phone.

Sometimes, fake science books use the ubiquity of electromagnetic radiation to claim that "all beings are in resonance", that the phase of the moon can affect your mood, that you can be healed by buying their crystals, or similar nonsense. This is impossible because the human body is quite insensitive to electromagnetic fields. People are regularly exposed to fields billions of times stronger than the ones we're talking about here, to no effect, such as in MRI scanners.

Comment: As a personal opinion, I prefer a less aggressive approach than the last paragraph.  Someone may indeed have a crystal which "resonates" with me.  Science doesn't have the truth, only models.  However, why such a resonance would be important when, as you say, far stronger fields course through us every day.  Why is *this* crystal different than every other object in the universe?  That particular question, then, has to be answered without borrowing any authority from science, because they've already used up all their science-based argument, and still haven't made the sale =)

Comment: But by starting from a position of recognizing science doesn't have all the answers, you avoid falling prey to any doubts about science's perfection that they might be able to introduce.